# what happens if you take the absolute value of a complex modulated signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications

I was going through some methods of eliminating carrier frequency offset (CFO). and one way is to take the absolute value of a received signal (somewhat like looking at the power of the signal)

[image]

and clearly the absolute value of a complex exponential is 1

[image]

therefore CFO is eliminated.

But i am not sure what are the cost of doing this? does the complex signal gets lost if i do the absolute value operation?

Comment: I think you're either mis-understanding the source or have a bad source, can you provide some more information on it or a link?

Comment: This question is totally un-understandable. What is $y_{nl}(t)$ or $n(t)$? What is the received signal and what is the carrier whose offset is to be eliminated? -1 pending editing to provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking absolute value will certainly eliminate the phase component but it depends on what kind of modulation you use. The cost of it will be huge for modulation schemes which depend on phase of signal (BPSK/QPSK/QAM etc).

For example for QPSK, suppose your transmitted baseband signal is $1+j1$, that is $\phi=\pi/4$. Due to CFO phase error of more than $\pm \pi/4$ the signal may end up in adjacent quadrant due to rotation. Taking absolute value will be of no use in this case. The CFO causes phase error to increase linearly, so if your data is long enough, the phase factor $2\pi\Delta ft$ can become more than $\pi/4$.